# Access SQL - is it possible to include/exclude columns in SELECT based on a variable?

Tags: sql, ms-access

If I have simple query like this:

```
SELECT Flag, Column1, Column2
FROM MyTable
WHERE Item = MyItem
```

This query is expected to return 1 row, like this:

```
Flag    Column1   Column2
---------------------------
Y       123       ABC
```

Can I choose to only include "Column1" if MyItem = "Y" and only include "Column2" if MyItem = "N"?

So I would want to see this:

```
Flag    Column1
--------------
Y       123
```

Or this:

```
Flag    Column2
----------------
N       ABC
```

I'm thinking it would include a `CASE` statement somewhere in the `SELECT` but not sure of the syntax. I tried this:

```
SELECT This,
CASE WHEN Flag = "Y" THEN Column1 ELSE NULL END,
CASE WHEN Flag = "N" THEN Column2 ELSE NULL END
FROM MyTable
WHERE Item = MyItem
```

But that gives a syntax error (missing operator)

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a conditional value.  Access does not support `case` but it does support `iif`:

```
select this,
       iif(flag = 'Y', column1, column2) as value
from MyTable
where Item = MyItem
```

Your text says that `MyItem` is `'N'` or `'Y'`.  I think the code sample (which uses `Flag`) makes more sense.

Comment: The user will enter `MyItem` and one of the returned columns is `Flag` .. but I see how this works now. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

As already said, there's no `CASE ... WHEN` statement in Access, but you have two possibilities: the [Switch Function](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/switch-function-HA001228918.aspx) and the [IIf Function](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/iif-function-HA001228853.aspx?CTT=1).

**- Switch Function example:**

```
SELECT Flag, Switch(flag = 'Y', column1, flag = 'N', column2) as Column
FROM MyTable
WHERE Item = MyItem
```

Note that in the Switch function, if none of the boolean expressions evaluate to True, Switch returns Null.

**- IIf Function example:**

```
SELECT Flag, IIf(flag = 'Y', column1, IIf(flag = 'N', column2, null)) as Column
FROM MyTable
WHERE Item = MyItem
```